# 1 or 2 describes for a function in mocha tests?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I am doing this tutorial on Mocha for Node apps.
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/testing-in-nodejs--net-35018

It has this code

```
describe("Tags", function(){
   describe("#parse()", function(){
       it("should parse long formed tags", function(){
           var args = ["--depth=4", "--hello=world"];
           var results = tags.parse(args);

           expect(results).to.have.a.property("depth", 4);
           expect(results).to.have.a.property("hello", "world");
       });
   });
});
```

Is there a reason I cannot just have one describe line?
Like this

```
describe("Tags #parse()", function(){
   it("should parse long formed tags", function(){
       var args = ["--depth=4", "--hello=world"];
       var results = tags.parse(args);

       expect(results).to.have.a.property("depth", 4);
       expect(results).to.have.a.property("hello", "world");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `describe` creates a different test and each `it` will test for a different "behavior" under the test.

When testing a class or module for example it is good style to create a top-level `describe("MyModule", ...)` and several nested `describe` calls, one for each method/function etc.

It all boils down to style and granularity of your tests. You could theoretically test your whole API with one describe and one it if you wanted. Making it granular means you have more fine-grained control when a test fails, when you refactor or change your API etc.

You are entirely free to design your tests the way you like them though.